# Map units relative to what?

Tags: epsg

If I have a map in say EPSG:2180, which represents coordinates is in meters,
what is this meter reading relative to? To start of map bounding box? World O,O?
What is the right way to reference a meter based coordinates in a map in given projection?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [definition of your CRS](https://epsg.io/2180)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Each projection may have a different origin (and may have a false origin applied as well). That's why there are lots of them (in some of them, the "meters" aren't even in meters). Unfortunately, GIS SE isn't a very effective construct to ask fundamental questions (especially multiple fundamental questions) -- we're more of a *problem-solving* site. A good primer on map projections could probably address your questions.

Comment: Each CRS has an own, specific center of origin from where coordinates are calculated in x and y direction. The link @Erik posted shows for your CRS: ***Center coordinates: 
509847.9 511024.24***

Comment: @Vince Sorry, I've seen a lot of similar questions here hence I asked. I'll be more cautious in the future. And big thank you for answering anyway, and not sending me to hell. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are relative to the origin of the coordinate reference system.  Here I create a simple CSV file with coordinate pairs as 0, 0.

[image]

In QGIS you could add that CSV as delimited text and define the data as referencing EPSG:2180.

[image]

This red dot is the origin of EPSG:2180.

[image]

Comment: Yes, and that would correlate with my map's lower corner bounding box specified in its WMTS capabilities response.